# Slim Php not recognizing gets

Tags: php, api, slim-3

I am just starting to work with Slim PHP. What could be the reason that get is not recognized on server?

This route works: it returns required text https://mywebsite/back/public
This route doesn't work (`Not Found`): https://mywebsite/back/public/countries

I have just installed slim framework and added new `index.php` file.

```
<?php
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';


    $app = new \Slim\App();

    $app->get('/', function($request, $response, $arg) {
        $response->write("This route works");
    });

    $app->get('/countries', function($request, $response, $arg) {
        $response->write("This route doesnt");
    });



    $app->run();

?>
```

Comment: Remove closing tag. Apache or Nginx? Does `https://mywebsite/back/public/index.php/countries` give results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using? If you are using version 4, you need to set the basePath.

```
$app->setBasePath('/back/public');
```

Also enable `mod_rewrite` and configure your .htaccess file.

I recommend you check this project on github [slimphp/Slim-Skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton). This is a boilerplate code for Slim 4 applications.

Comment: My problem was missing .htaccess file